# How to produce particle concentration in a region from list of particle coordinates

Tags: python, list, nested-lists, montecarlo

I am running a Monte Carlo simulation for the diffusion of particles. It outputs a list for each particle containing lists that correspond to coordinates where the particle has been. The list is a tracker of the location of a particle (position_tracker) and each particle has a separate list. ie.

position_tracker for particle 0 = `[(20, 24), (19, 24), (19, 24), (18, 23), (17, 22), (18, 21), (19, 21)]`

position_tracker for particle 1 = `[(21, 25), (21, 25), (21, 25)]`

I am trying to figure out how many particles are in a region of coordinates (`gr.tspace`) over time and then plot a graph with number of particles in the region against time.

The problem I am running into is 2 fold; 1. the particle position only updates when the position changes, so each of the lists containing the coordinates are different lengths. 2. This means that I don't know when in time each particle moves. I think a best guess will suffice for this.

This is where my attempt is at the moment:

The list of particle positions are stored in `gr.list_of_atoms[x].position_tracker[y]`

x indexing the particle and y indexing the coordinate

The below code is with the Monte Carlo simulation making 10 moves with 100 particles, Hence the for loops range of 99 and 9.

```
count_track = np.zeros((100,10))


for x in range (99):
    for x in range (9):
        if gr.list_of_atoms[x].position_tracker[y] in gr.tspace:
            count_track[x,y] = 1
            print('inside')
            y += 1
        else:
            print('outside')
            y += 1
```

I have tried creating a list of the list lengths and using this as the range for the for loop:

```
lngth =[]
for x in range (99) :
    lngth.append(len(gr.list_of_atoms[x].position_tracker))
```

I could not get this to work.

I am struggling and would appreciate any assistance

Comment: What is the question? Please read [ask].

Comment: `for x in range (99): for x in range (9):` - both loops use the same variable name was that intended?

Comment: If you cannot relate a particle's position to a *time* you will never be able to plot a time history for a given location.  At a minimum it seems that the simulation that produces the data should included *time* (the current step of the simulation) along with the x and y coordinates - `(x,y,z)`. Maybe the simulation should also append to the particle's *tracker* every step, even if the position does not change.

Comment: I see my question is vague and I have rewritten my code to now have a coordinate point at every time step. I have now submitted a new question which is hopefully more concise.